# POST request forbidden

Tags: javascript, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am using django-rest-framework. I have a few APIs which I use to GET data. When I am testing a new API to post information, I am getting a 403 forbidden while making the request as vanilla xhr object, as well as using jQuery. The same API is working properly from Postman and django-rest-framework API interface as well. What can be the reason for this?

Comment: add "/" on the end of post url

Comment: Its already there, still getting the error:
$.post( "http://localhost:8000/foo/api/comment/25632/", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );

Comment: localhost:8000/foo/api/comment/25632/

Comment: Check if it is blocked by CORS policy or not in the network tab.

Comment: Oh my bad, I added the trailing slash, but still the same. No its not blocked by CORS.

Comment: Can you post some screenshot with more details regarding the error? Maybe try sending the POST data directly from REST Framework's interface (and send some screenshots)?

Comment: Yeah I got the issue. I was not sending the the csrf token in the http headers. I added that as a X-CSRFToken header, now it is working flawlessly.